# How to capture mongodb live analytics

Tags: mongodb

As per my current analysis, I got to know, We have two approaches to capture mongodb db live analytics.

1) Mongodb provides rest api url to see the live analytics.

2) Run mongo Administrative command like "db.runCommand({"top" :1})"

But both approach required administrative permission on mongodb server. Is there any other way to capture analytics which don't required admin permission.

Comment: I am not sure what type of analytics you are trying to capture, but have you tried using mongo's MMS agent (mms.mongodb.com)?

Comment: Yes, i have also used MMS agent and i want to capture almost same data what MMS is capturing. I want to use any other tools that can be host on my personal server.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to capture analytics which don't required admin permission.

Not as at MongoDB 2.4: most of the interesting administrative commands to gather server-level metrics require the [`clusterAdmin` privilege](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#clusterAdmin) if you have authentication enabled.

> i have also used MMS agent and i want to capture almost same data what MMS is capturing. I want to use any other tools that can be host on my personal server.

The MMS Monitoring Service documentation includes a list of [Database Commands Used by the Monitoring Agent](http://mms.mongodb.com/help/monitoring/reference/#database-commands-used-by-the-monitoring-agent) if you would like to capture similar information.

If you're not deadset on writing your own monitoring tool, there are plenty of open source options including plugins for monitoring systems like Nagios or Zenoss.  The [Administration UIs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/) section of the MongoDB manual lists some of the available admin UIs and monitoring tools, but there are likely others if you do a bit of research.